# std::is_rvalue_reference inside template function with rvalue reference parameter

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct Empty {};

template <typename V>
void add(V&& element)
{
    static_assert( std::is_rvalue_reference<V>::value, "V is not a rvalue reference");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    add(Empty());   

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get why static_assert fail here, `V` isn't equal to `V&&` here ?

Comment: `V` is deduced as `Empty`, so `V` is not an rvalue reference type; `V&&` is.

Comment: but if I forward it, it would be deduced as V&&, I have the feeling I miss something here

Comment: Take a look at how `std::forward` is implemented, maybe that'll make it clear.

Comment: You want `is_rvalue_reference<V&&>::value` since `V` will never be deduced to be an rvalue reference type. But it may be deduced to be an lvalue reference type (special deduction rule that enables perfect forwarding) in which case `V&&` is also an lvalue reference type due to reference collapsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`V` is not the rvalue-reference - `decltype(element)` is (if `element` is an rvalue). `V` is simply the general type of `element`. Specifically:

```
typename std::remove_reference<decltype(element)>::type; // V
```

Comment: Not exactly, if `element` is deduced as an lvalue-reference than V will be `T&`.

Comment: @kennytm I think the edit resolved your concern.